# How can I find the intersection point between 2 transformed exponential functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, exponential-function

I am trying to find the intersection point betweens 2 exponential functions, where the x of the point of intersection is:

> $5 \cdot 3^x - 7 = 2^{x+3}$

I found myself stuck at

> $x = \log_3( (2^{x+3} + 7 ) / 5 )$

How can I solve this equation for x?

On my calculator, I found that the answer is supposed to be

> $x\approx 1.73$

Comment: Are you familiar with this result? Perhaps you can apply it here? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Change_of_Base_of_Logarithm

Comment: Why do you think that there is a nice algebraic solution?

Comment: @Andrei Sorry, I shouldn't have said "algebraically".  I just want to find the point of intersection between 2 functions.

Comment: I've got that. You can probably just calculate it numerically. I don't think it's some nice expression.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfy gets the numerical root as about
1.7348162477070183112.

The inverse symbolic calculator
doesn't return anything.

My guess is that
this is a JaN
(Just a Number)
with no redeeming value.